# When do I need to use the alternative macros for bitwise and logical operators inside the header file of iso646.h?

Tags: c, token, compatibility, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I know that in the header of `iso646.h`, the following eleven marco constants are defined to provide alternative descriptions of the bitwise and logical operators:

`and` is a macro for `&&`.

`and_eq` is a macro for `&=`.

`bitand` is a macro for `&`.

`bitor` is a macro for `|`.

`compl` is a macro for `~`.

`not` is a macro for `!`.

`not_eq` is a macro for `!=`.

`or` is a macro for `||`.

`or_eq` is a macro for `|=`

`xor` is a macro for `^`.

`xor_eq` is a macro for `^=`.

---

But when do I need to use these alternative macros?

- Under which circumstances do I need to use the alternative macros for bitwise and logical operators inside of the header file of `iso646.h`?

Comment: If the `&` key on your keyboard is broken :-)

Comment: @NateEldredge Or when I can´t find it (quickly enough) or I´m just too lazy to do the keystroke. :/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use it if your encoding does not implement the full ASCII repertoire:

> C derived its repertoire from the ASCII codeset.  Unfortunately the ASCII repertoire is not a subset of all other commonly used character sets, and widespread practice in Europe is not to implement all of ASCII either, but use some parts of its collating sequence for special national characters.
>
> The solution is an internationally agreed-upon repertoire, in terms of which an international representation of C can be defined.  The ISO has defined such a standard: ISO 646 describes an invariant subset of ASCII.
>
> The characters in the ASCII repertoire used by C and absent from the ISO 646 repertoire are:
>
> ```
>     # [ ] { } \ | ~ ^
> ```

*Taken from the [ANSI C Rationale, [2.2.1.1 Trigraph sequences]](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c89/rationale/b.html#ISO-646-2-2-1-1)*

As pointed out by @chqrlie, this was an important issue to take into consideration in the 1980s but much less relevant today.

This is also the reason trigraphs were introduced (explained further along in the same section). As such when a non-ASCII encoding is used, the macros are replaced by their trigraph versions in `iso646.h`.

Comment: I can´t see the relation from the cited quite to the macros for the bitwise and logical operators in `iso646`? What have trigraphs to do with it? In `iso646.h` there are no trigraphs.

Comment: You might want to add that these considerations were current in the early 1980' and became largely irrelevant thereafter, even before the C language was normalized by ANSI. There is no reason to use these macros or the trigraphs today.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio If you character encoding does not have the `~` symbol, you would have to replace it with `??-`. For better readability, it was decided to provide macros to make the code compatible with a wider group of encodings: `compl a` works whether the `~` character exists in the current encoding or not and is much more legible than `??- a`.

Comment: @chqrlie you are correct, I doubt there is much need for that header these days but it stays there.

Comment: @chqrlie What about writing code for old systems and backwards-compatibility?

Comment: @SimonDoppler But the characters of `# [ ] { } \ ` are not provided as macros in `iso646.h`. It are only macros for logical and bitwise operators. What about that?

Comment: @SimonDoppler And why do the macros work when the character set does not support these characters? Is it only meant for giving input over keyboard but inside of the implementation, the respective characters could be used properly?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio trigraphs are part of the core language. The header may be implemented in terms of them on the systems lacking the ``#[]{}\`` characters.

Comment: @Ruslan But the characters of `#[]{}\ ` aren´t provided as macros in `iso646.h`. How can the header be used for them?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio remember the _as if_ rule. Inclusion of the header makes the macros defined therein work _as if_ they expanded to these characters. The characters themselves don't have to exist anywhere at all.

Comment: @SimonDoppler One thing to ask more: You said - *You should use it if your encoding does not implement the full ASCII repertoire* - Hoiw will I know if my encoding set doesn´t has a full ASCII repertoire?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Usually, your text editor should be able to tell you which encoding you have (and you should be able to change the text encoding of your file). From there you must look that encoding up to check if it fully supports ASCII (the [ISO 646 Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_646) lists quite a few encodings that do not support ASCII). Unless you are using an very old non-US system or a very exotic one, there is almost no chance that the encoding does not fully contain the ASCII character set.